# graphics object is painted twice

Tags: java

here is code that generate and paint one of tetramino figure every 5 sec.
However, the figure is drown twice and, therefore, twists the original picture.

Here tetramino figure consist of 10x10 pixel blocks.
Constructor Figure tells position of the blocks and color.
method paint(Graphics g) drows Figure f block by block.

```
import java.applet.*;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D;


import javax.swing.Timer;
public class Tetris extends Applet  {

    Dimension size;
    int x1,y1;
    private int xs=0,ys=0;


    public int getXs() {
        return xs;
    }
    public void setXs(int xs) {
        this.xs = xs;
    }
    public int getYs() {
        return ys;
    }
    public void setYs(int ys) {
        this.ys = ys;
    }
    public void rotate(){

    }
    public Figure generate(){
        Figure i = new Figure(new int[][]{new int[]{1},new int[]{1},new int[]{1},new int[]{1}},Color.CYAN);
        Figure j = new Figure(new int[][]{new int[]{1,0,0}, new int[]{1,1,1}},Color.BLUE);
        Figure l = new Figure(new int[][]{new int[]{0,0,1}, new int[]{1,1,1}},Color.ORANGE);
        Figure o = new Figure(new int[][]{new int[]{1,1}, new int[]{1,1}},Color.YELLOW);
        Figure s = new Figure(new int[][]{new int[]{0,1,1}, new int[]{1,1,0}},Color.GREEN);
        Figure t = new Figure(new int[][]{new int[]{1,1,1}, new int[]{0,1,0}},Color.PINK);
        Figure z = new Figure(new int[][]{new int[]{1,1,0}, new int[]{0,1,1}},Color.RED);

        Figure[] genSet = {i,j,l,o,s,t,z};
        int index =((int) (Math.random() * 7)) ;
        //System.out.println(index);
        return  genSet[index];
    }
    public void drop(){

    }
    public void shift(){

    }
    public void movecheck(){

    }
    public void actiondelay(){
        ActionListener actionlistener = new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionevent){
                repaint();
            }

        };
        Timer timer = new Timer(5000,actionlistener);
        timer.start();
    }
    public void init(){
        setSize(200,400);
        setBackground(Color.black);
        size = getSize();

    }

    public void paint(Graphics g){

        super.paint(g);
        System.out.println("________________");
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
        Figure f = generate();
        int length = f.getX()[0].length;
        for(int j =0; j<f.getX().length;j++){
            System.out.println();
            ys = 0;                 
            for(int i=0;i<length;i++){                      

                if (f.getX()[j][i] == 1){
                    Rectangle2D p = new Rectangle2D.Double(xs,xs,xs+10,ys+10);
                    g2d.setColor(f.getY());
                    g2d.draw(p);
                    //g2d.drawRect(p.x, p.y, p.width, p.height);    
                    //g2d.fillRect(p.x, p.y, p.width, p.height);                    
                    //System.out.println("widnth: " +p.width + " | height: " + p.height + " end ");
                    System.out.print("*");
                }
                else System.out.print(" ");
                ys+=10;             
            }
            xs+=10;
        }
        xs=0;
        ys=0;
        actiondelay();                      
       //g.setColor(Color.white);
       //g.drawRect(45, 95, 55, 105);        
    }


}


import java.awt.Color;

public class Figure{
    int[][] x;
    Color y;
    public Figure(int[][] x , Color y){
        this.x=x;
        this.y=y;
    }
    public int[][] getX() {
        return x;
    }
    public void setX(int[][] x) {
        this.x = x;
    }
    public Color getY() {
        return y;
    }
    public void setY(Color y) {
        this.y = y;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your image is not twisted because figure is drawn twice, but because you have few mistakes in `new Rectangle2D.Double(xs,xs,xs+10,ys+10);`

1. at starting `x` and `y` positions you used `xs` two times instead of `xs` and `ys`
2. your `width` and `hight` isn't fixed value but related with `xs` and `ys`

Also your loop was increasing `xs` instead of `ys` when you ware going to new row.

Try to replace your `paint()` method by this:

```
public void paint(Graphics g){

    super.paint(g);
    System.out.println("________________");
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
    Figure f = generate();
    int length = f.getX()[0].length;
    for(int j =0; j<f.getX().length; j++){
        System.out.println();

        for(int i=0; i<f.getX()[0].length; i++){                      

            if (f.getX()[j][i] == 1){
                Rectangle2D p = new Rectangle2D.Double(xs, ys, 10, 10);
                g2d.setColor(f.getY());
                g2d.draw(p);
                //g2d.drawRect(p.x, p.y, p.width, p.height);    
                //g2d.fillRect(p.x, p.y, p.width, p.height);                    
                //System.out.println("widnth: " +p.width + " | height: " + p.height + " end ");
                System.out.print("*");
            }
            else System.out.print(" ");
            xs+=10;
        }
        xs = 0;
        ys+=10;             
    }
    xs=0;
    ys=0;
    actiondelay();                      
   //g.setColor(Color.white);
   //g.drawRect(45, 95, 55, 105);        
}
```

---

Also `javax.swing.Timer(int delay, ActionListener listener)` is type of cyclic Thread so you shouldn't create few instances of it if you want to perform its action once per time set in `delay`. At your place I would move code from `actiondelay` to `init`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing a call to `g2d.dispose()` in your `paint()` method. I'm not sure if this will fix the problem, but it won't hurt to try it.

Comment: hrmm...unfortunately, I am not on a machine where I can test this out. I'll take a closer look when I can. Until then, I hope someone else can provide further assistance.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in how you are using your `Timer`.  I don't know why you insist on creating a new timer on each "paint" cycle.

You do not control the paint cycle, Java does.  So basically, what's happened, is that every time your component is painted (which could be a number of times between your `Timer` events), you are creating a new `Timer`, which **repeats** every 5 seconds.  That means your running ***n*** timers, which will cause you lots of fun stuff...

Instead, create a single timer:

```
@Override
public void start() {

    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {

            timer = new Timer(5000, new ActionListener() {

                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                    repaint();

                }
            });

            timer.setInitialDelay(5000);
            timer.setCoalesce(true);
            timer.start(); // Repeats by default...

        }
    });

}
```

DO NOT ALTER ANY THING IN THE PAINT METHODS.  Just don't  You could be triggering more paint requests, which will eventually overload the EDT and run your CPU up to 100% in no short order.